# Filtering Max Date from the second table of a query

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to run a query from two tables, one that doesn't have dates, and one that does.

I only want the latest date recorded result from the second table as it would make the data incorrect.

I am using the following query in MYSQL.

```
$sql = "SELECT acoll.PIECE_NO, odd.FROM_POS
FROM acoll, odd
WHERE acoll.PIECE_NO = odweld.PIECE and odd.DATE IN

    (SELECT
       MAX(DATE)
     FROM
       odd
       )

GROUP BY odd.FROM_POS" ;
```

It doesn't seem to be giving me any result, I've been trying lots of different ways for hours, and can't seem to crack it,

Sorry if this is a really amateur question, I'm brand new to mysql and php.

Please let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: I'm surprised MySql allowed you to use a reserved word: DATE, as the name of a column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is a filtering `join`:

```
select  *
from    acoll t1
join    odd t2
on      t1.piece_no = t2.piece
join    (
        select  piece
        ,       max(date) as max_date
        from    odd
        group by
                piece
        ) filter
on      filter.piece = t2.piece
        and filter.max_date = t2.date
```

Or a correlated subquery:

```
select  *
from    acoll t1
join    odd t2
on      t1.piece_no = t2.piece
where   t2.date = 
        (
        select  max(date)
        from    odd t2_max
        where   t2_max.piece = t2.piece
        )
```

More solutions can be found in the [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) tag.

Comment: I liked the first way of self join correlated way might affect performance +1

Comment: @Andomar I used the correlated subquery code and it worked absolutely perfectly! Thanks a lot man..

Answer (score 0):

What I believe you need to look into is the `HAVING` clause.

Here is an example:

```
SELECT 
    a.PIECE_NO
    , o.FROM_POS
FROM 
    acoll a
    INNER JOIN odd o ON a.PIECE_NO = o.PIECE 
GROUP BY  
    a.PIECE_NO
    , o.FROM_POS
HAVING 
    o.DATE = MAX(o.DATE)
```

Comment: The `having` clause can use column that appear in the `group by` list, or are in an aggregate function.  You're using `o.Date`, which is neither, so it is not allowed in the `having` clause.